# Firefox / Chrome - WebRTC mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() - different result

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, webcam, citrix

I have a problem in our Citrix environment.
I get different video and audio devices in [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KTxb.png) and [firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9suK9.png) on the same webpage. I guess that chrome sees webcams from a different session or webcams that are no longer available.
Is there any way to change this behavior in chrome to get same results as in firefox?

Comment: it is rather difficult to answer if you don't give samples of what you see and how this differs. Note that both browsers may restrict the available cam/mic devices to one of each kind until you call getUsermedia.

Comment: You should see screenshots if you follow the links for chrome and firefox.
I used the following webpage in the screenshots https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/
It's the same for every site i tested (teams, jitsi, webex)

Comment: sounds like a bug in chrome if it keeps old devices, reporting https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list is likely the only way to get this solved.